# How to access the addresses after i get out of the loop?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct data {
  int x;
  data *ptr;
};

int main() {
 int i = 0;
  while( i >=3 ) {
    data *pointer = new data;  // pointer points to the address of data
    pointer->ptr = pointer;    // ptr contains the address of pointer
    i++;
  }
 system("pause");
}
```

Let us assume after iterating 3 times :

```
 ptr had address = 100 after first loop
 ptr had address = 200 after second loop
 ptr had address = 300 after third loop
```

Now the questions are :

1. Do all the three addresses that were being assigned to ptr exist in the memory after the program gets out of the loop ?
2. If yes , what is the method to access these addresses after i get out of the loop ?

Comment: This code has numerous problems. 1. You're leaking memory. 2. `using namespace std;` 3. That's a `for` loop, make it one. 4. and so on

Comment: Are you trying to make a linked list?

Comment: @ RTS Not here , but it was related.

Comment: @Suhail Gupta  Did you see my post, was that useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, there will be no memory allocated for any ptr with the code you have.

```
int i = 0;
while( i >= 3)
```

This will not enter the `while` loop at all.

However, if you are looking to access the ptr contained inside the `struct` then you can try this. I am not sure what you are trying to achieve by assigning the ptr with its own struct object address. The program below will print the value of `x` and the address assigned to `ptr`.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct data {
  int x;
  data *ptr;
};

int main() {
 int i = 0;
 data pointer[4];
  while( i <=3 ) {
    pointer[i].x = i;
    pointer[i].ptr = &pointer[i];  
    i++;
  }

for( int i = 0; i <= 3; i++ )
{
   cout<< pointer[i].x << endl;
   cout<< pointer[i].ptr << endl;
}

}
```

OUTPUT:

```
0
0xbf834e98
1
0xbf834ea0
2
0xbf834ea8
3
0xbf834eb0
```

Personally, when I know the number of iterations I want to do, I choose `for` loops and I use `while` only when I am looking to iterate unknown number of times before a logical expression is satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Well the memory is reserved but you have no pointer to the memory so that's whats called a memory leak (reserved memory but no way to get to it). You may want to have an array of data* to save these pointers so you can delete them when you are done with them or use them later.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot guess what you are trying to achieve...
But Me thinks, you are trying to achieve similar to this....
[image: pic]

But, If you want to make linked list using your implementation, you can try this...

```
#include<iostream.h>
struct data {
  int x;
  data *ptr;
  data()
  {
   x = -1;
   ptr = NULL;
  }
};

data *head = new data();
data *pointer = head;

int main() {
 int i = 0;

  while( i <=3 ) {
    data *pointer = new data();
    pointer->x = /*YOUR DATA*/;
   ::pointer->ptr = pointer;
   ::pointer = pointer;
   i++;
  }

  i=0;
   data* pointer = head->next;
   while( i <=3 ) {
   cout<<pointer->x;
   pointer = pointer->ptr;
   i++;
   }
  system("pause");

}
```

This will print , the elements in the linked list;